# Changing list as values in dict into normal value in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with values in list. But I want to change them from `list` to a normal `dict` value.
So it's looking like this:

```
{1: {'A': { 1: [5], 16: [5], 17: [4],
           20: [9], 22: [5], 26: [4],
           33: [2], 34: [4], 42: [2],
           47: [4], 72: [4], 80: [2]}}}
```

And this is the expected output: (removing the square brackets)

```
{1: {'A': { 1: 5, 16: 5, 17: 4,
           20: 9, 22: 5, 26: 4,
           33: 2, 34: 4, 42: 2,
           47: 4, 72: 4, 80: 2}}}
```

These are like extracts from my actual data, which roughly looks like this. So there's a set of these data in each of the `dict`s (which is like 3*3=9 in total)

```
{1: {"A": {}, "B": {}, "C":{}},
 2: {"A": {}, "B": {}, "C":{}},
 3: {"A": {}, "B": {}, "C":{}}}
```

I see a lot other questions turning a `list` into a value in `dict`. But I'm trying to do the opposite (changing my values to normal values instead of being in a `list`)

Would be great if you've seen other threads with similar problems and can direct me to them.

Comment: Its a single element list so you can access the list as `my_list[0]` and reassign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive solution (`dct` is your dictionary from the question):

```py
def remove_lists(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return {k: remove_lists(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        return remove_lists(d[0])
    return d


print(remove_lists(dct))
```

Prints:

```
{1: {'A': {1: 5, 16: 5, 17: 4, 20: 9, 22: 5, 26: 4, 33: 2, 34: 4, 42: 2, 47: 4, 72: 4, 80: 2}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the inner dict, and get the index 0 in each list

```
# solution for your specific case
values = {1: {'A': {1: [5], 16: [5], 17: [4], 20: [9], 22: [5], 26: [4],
                    33: [2], 34: [4], 42: [2], 47: [4], 72: [4], 80: [2]}}}

values = {1: {'A': {k: v[0] for k, v in values[1]['A'].items()}}}
```

And the generic code for any 3-level dict

```
values = {
    outerKey: {
        innerKey: {k: v[0] for k, v in innerDict.items()}
        for innerKey, innerDict in outerDict.items()
    } for outerKey, outerDict in values.items()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! can I do the same thing if I don't specifiy "1" and "A"? 
Cuz I actually have a nested dict, and I would want to apply removing the list for each of the values in all the nested dicts
Maybe I'll update my question abit

Comment: Thanks again, it works perfectly! Sorry cuz accepting another answer tho.. SInce it was a little more straight forward, for say if other people have even more layers of dict :)